# How to remove gap between header and next element

Tags: html, css

I have got a little space between header (colored red) and the next figure element (colored blue). Why does this space appears although I have set margin and padding equal to zero using universal selector?

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html
{
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
}

body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}

.firstheader
{
    background-color:#CC1C0D;
    height: 117px;
}

img{
    height: 117px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.logofigure
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 117px;
}

.tit_image{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    
}

nav
{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 35px;
}

.nav>li
{
    
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    float: left;
    /*position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left:100px;*/
}
.nav li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
   
}

.About_us_sub
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
    height: 145px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    
}

.About_us_sub li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #CC1C0D;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 60x;
    height: 15px;
}


.sub_second{
    height: 32px; 
    /** we specify the height of this li to solve the problem of displaying sub list when hovering below the about_us item.
    By default, the height of About us will take the length of the sub menu, so when we specify height then the about us box will 
    not expand**/
}

.sub_second:hover .About_us_sub{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../CSS/General_Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="firstheader">
        <figure class="logofigure">
            <img src="../HTML/complete/complete/vectacorp/images/logo.png">
        </figure>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="sub_first"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="sub_second"><a href="">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="About_us_sub">
                        <li>OverView</li>
                        <li>History</li>
                        <li>Management</li>
                        <li>Career</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub third"><a href="">Solutions</a></li>
                <li class="sub fourth"><a href="">Support</a></li>
                <li class="sub fifth"><a href="">Contact US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <figure class="tit_image">

        </figure>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is happening because of the `relative` position of your `nav` element. Relative positioning keeps the elements height, width, padding etc. in the dom where it initially was placed, but moves the visual aspect relative to the left, top that you give it. You have this in-between your header and body in the code, I would put it before both `figure` elements and remove relative positioning

Comment: I set a negative margin (-4px) to the next element after the header and it works. Do you think there is an impact of using negative margin

Comment: It seems to have something to do with line height. After simplifying the example a bit it seems like setting line-height: 0; on the header element removes the gap. Not sure why though at the moment. E.g. This example still has a gap: https://jsfiddle.net/9p2L41s7/

Comment: Actually, it seems like it has something to do with the text inside the elements. Adding a character to the red and green boxes in my previous example fixes the problem, as does setting vertical-align: bottom; https://jsfiddle.net/9p2L41s7/2/ Will have to investigate this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The space is occupied by your relatively positioned `<nav>`. `relative` positioned elements do take up space in normal flow.

In the example below I've updated it to be `absolute` positioned, which doesn't take up space in normal flow.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html {
  background-color: #DFE3E6;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 960px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.firstheader {
  background-color: #CC1C0D;
  height: 117px;
}

img {
  height: 117px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logofigure {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 117px;
}

.tit_image {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: visible;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 35px;
}

.nav>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  float: left;
  /*position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left:100px;*/
}

.nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.About_us_sub {
  float: left;
  background-color: #DFE3E6;
  height: 145px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.About_us_sub li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #CC1C0D;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 60x;
  height: 15px;
}

.sub_second {
  height: 32px;
  /** we specify the height of this li to solve the problem of displaying sub list when hovering below the about_us item.
    By default, the height of About us will take the length of the sub menu, so when we specify height then the about us box will 
    not expand**/
}

.sub_second:hover .About_us_sub {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="../CSS/General_Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="firstheader">
    <figure class="logofigure">
      <img src="../HTML/complete/complete/vectacorp/images/logo.png">
    </figure>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="sub_first"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="sub_second"><a href="">About Us</a>
          <ul class="About_us_sub">
            <li>OverView</li>
            <li>History</li>
            <li>Management</li>
            <li>Career</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub third"><a href="">Solutions</a></li>
        <li class="sub fourth"><a href="">Support</a></li>
        <li class="sub fifth"><a href="">Contact US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <figure class="tit_image">

    </figure>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Edit: the `display: inline-block;` also creates small margin on firefox.

```
.logofigure {
  /* display: inline-block; */
   height: 117px;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, in Firefox your example still has a gap.

Answer (score 0):

This gap is a result of how browsers lay out inline elements, such as the `.logofigure` and `nav` elements in your example. Since they are inline the browser is treating them like part of a line of text, positioning the bottom of each element at the "baseline" of the text, above the bottom of characters that hang down below the baseline like g, q, j, etc. This leaves a small gap between the bottom of the line of "text" and the bottom of the `.logofigure` and `nav` elements. The `.tit_image` element is positioned at the top of the "next line", as it is a block element. This leaves a small gap.

To fix this problem you can tell the browser to instead position these elements at the very bottom of the line of "text" (below the baseline) by styling them as `vertical-align: bottom;`:

```
.logofigure
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

nav
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

The end result:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html
{
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
}

body
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}

.firstheader
{
    background-color:#CC1C0D;
    height: 117px;
}

img{
    height: 117px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.logofigure
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 117px;
}

.tit_image{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    
}

nav
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 35px;
}

.nav>li
{
    
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    float: left;
    /*position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    left:100px;*/
}
.nav li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
   
}

.About_us_sub
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #DFE3E6;
    height: 145px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
    
}

.About_us_sub li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #CC1C0D;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 60x;
    height: 15px;
}


.sub_second{
    height: 32px; 
    /** we specify the height of this li to solve the problem of displaying sub list when hovering below the about_us item.
    By default, the height of About us will take the length of the sub menu, so when we specify height then the about us box will 
    not expand**/
}

.sub_second:hover .About_us_sub{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../CSS/General_Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="firstheader">
        <figure class="logofigure">
            <img src="../HTML/complete/complete/vectacorp/images/logo.png">
        </figure>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="sub_first"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="sub_second"><a href="">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="About_us_sub">
                        <li>OverView</li>
                        <li>History</li>
                        <li>Management</li>
                        <li>Career</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub third"><a href="">Solutions</a></li>
                <li class="sub fourth"><a href="">Support</a></li>
                <li class="sub fifth"><a href="">Contact US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <figure class="tit_image">

        </figure>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```